# Сумма, делящаяся на три C++

Tags: c++, олимпиада, сложность

**Условие: (После - моё решение, вопрос и комментарии)**

Необходимо найти самый большой непрерывный фрагмент в массиве a1, a2... aN, сумма элементов которого делится на 3.

**Входные данные**

В первой строке входного файла содержится число N ≤ 100 000. Во второй строке входного файла следуют N чисел, по модулю не превосходящих 10^9 — элементы массива.

**Выходные данные**

Выведите два числа — индексы начала и конца фрагмента. Если таких фрагментов несколько, то выведите фрагмент с минимальным индексом начала.

Если ответа не существует, то выведите единственное число −1.

**Примеры**

Ввод_1 >

*4*

*1 2 3 4*

Вывод_1 <

*1 3*

---

Ввод_2 >

*5*

*1 2 3 4 5*

Вывод_2 <

*1 5*

**Подсказка: Обратите внимание, что в С++ при делении отрицательного числа на положительное мы получим отрицательный остаток.**

**Мой гневный спич:**
Первый раз пишу что-либо на форумах, так как впервые столкнулся с тем, что не могу решить задачу. Прошу просмотреть мой код и помочь найти ошибку. Что ожидают от меня составители задачи: решить задачу нужно с использованием линейного алгоритма и префиксных сумм (также посмотрите на подсказку выше). Я выяснил, что самым оптимальным подходом к решению задачи является **просмотр остатков деления префиксных сумм на 3**. Сейчас покажу всё на примере. Возьмём массив из первого примера : **1 2 3 4 5**. Теперь на основе этого массива составим массив префиксных сумм размером **n + 1** (Так как априори в таком массиве первым членом является 0): **0 1 3 6 10 15**. Теперь найдём остаток от деления на 3 каждого из элементов получившегося массива: **0 1 0 0 1 0**. А теперь в этом массиве из ноликов и единичек (Ещё может быть и 2 как остаток) найдем пару из одинаковых чисел (0 и 0; 1 и 1; 2 и 2) такую, что члены подходящей нам пары были как можно дальше друг друга (Так как мы ищем самый длинный фрагмент). **Обратите внимание, что нам всего лишь нужно найти первое вхождение остатков 0, 1, 2 в массив, а дальше сравнивать их со следующими за ними элементами, которые имеют тот же остаток от деления на 3, так мы сможем достичь максимально возможной длины фрагмента.** В данном случае подходящей парой будут два нолика (на нулевом месте и на шестом месте). Ответом будет фрагмент от первого места в массиве "a" до пятого места (Нам нужно будет немного пошаманить с индексами, так как размеры массива "a" и массива префиксных сумм различаются + индексация массива "а" начинается с 1, а не с 0, вы увидите в решении). У меня все, смотрите комменты к решению.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    long long n, elem;
    vector <long long> a;
    cin >> n;

    for (long long i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        cin >> elem;
        a.push_back(elem);
    }

    vector <long long> s (3, -1);
    s[0] = 0;
    vector <long long> e (3, -1);
    vector <long long> p (n + 1, 0);

    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; ++i){
        p[i] = p[i - 1] + a[i - 1];
    }


    long long maxlen = 0;
    long long mmax = -1;
    long long m;

    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; ++i){

        if (p[i] < 0){
            m = (p[i] * -1) % 3;

            if (m == 1){
                m = 2;
            } else {
                if (m == 2){
                    m = 1;
                }
            }

        } else {
            m = p[i] % 3;
        }



        if (s[m] < 0){
            s[m] = i;
        } else {
            e[m] = i - 1;
            if (i - s[m] > maxlen){
                maxlen = i - s[m];
                mmax = m;
            }
        }
    }

    if (mmax >= 0){
        cout << s[mmax] + 1 << " " << e[mmax] + 1;
    } else {
        cout << mmax;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: считайте сумму всех чисел. Если не делится на 3, то остаток равен 1 или 2. Проверьте остаток деления  последнего и первого числа и суммируйте их остаток к остатку от общей суммы, потом сумму этих остатков и остаток общей суммы , потом предпоследнюю и вторую по такой же логике, пока сумма этих остатков не равен 3

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. Я обновил свой код, сделал его гораздо короче, можете взглянуть. Он тоже работает, но не на всех тестах.

Comment: Жаль конечно, что спрашивали про С++, а товарищ переправил на тему с Питоном. В общем, лови, тестируй ...https://ideone.com/WGjDcB

Comment: Спасибо, что откликнулись, но я уже решил данную задачу. С 28 ПОПЫТКИ, С 28 ПОПЫТКИ... 28 УДАРОВ НОЖОМ, СИРИУС, ТЫ ДЕЙСТВОВАЛ НАВЕРНЯКА, ДА??? (Только фанаты Детройта поймут). Люди, которые не могут решить, обратите внимание на отрицательные числа: -8 % 3 не равно 2, -8 % 3 = 1.

Comment: Кому нужно, прикреплю решение здесь после окончания данного учебного модуля.

Comment: Как и обещал, прикрепил правильное решение, прошло проверку на Сириусе. Не писал на этот раз комментарии, так как лень. Скажу лишь то, что в коде провожу некоторые манипуляции с m, если p[i] отрицательно, так как C++ неверно считает остаток от деления отрицательных чисел на некоторое положительное число. Названия переменных скопировал из ответа на одноимённый вопрос на Питоне.